Complex loop calc in dbt + postgres
I need to recursively/cyclically calculate data by months with intermediate saves to the database, as the next period will be calculated/saved based on these data.
Details:

We have data based on which a month's calculations are made.
The next month is calculated based on these results, and so on until all missing months are calculated and saved.
Each monthly calculation involves 4-5 complex views.

In another stack (not dbt + airflow), this is solved as follows:

Calculate the month based on initial data.
Save the results to a technical table.
Calculate the next month based on the technical table.
Repeat until completion.

In dbt, this can theoretically be implemented in several ways:

Write a custom materialization scheme.
Adapt the experimental insert-by-period.
Use templates to generate the entire calculation through Jinja in one pass (though this could be cumbersome and resource-intensive).

Another considered option is to create simple models for the initial and n-th monthly calculations and organize multiple runs via airflow:
How to run tasks sequentially in a loop in an Airflow DAG?
However, the customer has limit access to airflow for us, making DAG debugging inconvenient.
Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be correctly implemented in dbt? Is there a proper way to use insert-by-period or another approach?
Thank you in advance!
When attempting to use insert-by-period, the following error occurred:
column "__period_filter__" does not exist
LINE 15: where __PERIOD_FILTER__


Advice, and maybe related, don't use UPPER case in your object names. Never. Ever. PostgreSQL will treat _ _PERIOD_FILTER_ _ as_ _period_filter_ _. But if you created the column as "_ PERIOD_FILTER _" (using double quotes), there won't be a match and you get a does not exist

Yes, but in this materialization it PERIOD_FILTER - kinda placeholder used by materialization code, so i think during materialization it should find it and change it for every period during multiple runs.

The error message suggests otherwise, or did you modify the error message?
